# How To use custom view in ActionBar in Fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have on activity which extends Fragment Activity ... in that i want to set custom action bar... i have tried in this way.. but this is not working

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
bar = getActionBar();
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                    .parseColor("#0194bf")));

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) mCustomView
                    .findViewById(R.id.action_title);
            txtTitle.setText("Recipe List");
            txtTitle.setTextSize(22);
            txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            bar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
}
```

This is my custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: "This is not working" is not a good line to describe your problem. Post your logcat. So that we will understand the issue.

Comment: bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); add this in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget this line :

> actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you a thousand times over!